# cURL with --data-binary trying to automate with rest-assured throws 500 error

Tags: curl, rest-assured

I've cURL as below

```
curl -H 'Host: api.staging.test.com' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' -H 'user-agent: okhttp/3.10.0' --data-binary '{"emailId":"test@test.com","password":"test123"}' --compressed 'https://api.staging.test.com/user/develop-account/v1/session?storeId=100'
```

I'm trying to automate this with `rest-assured` as below

```
request = given().
                        log().all().
                                auth().basic("test@test.com", "test123").
                                header("Host", HOST_HEADER).
                                header("user-agent", USER_AGENT).
                                header("accept", ACCEPT).
                                header("content-type", CONTENT_TYPE);

response = request.when().
           post("https://api.staging.test.com/user/develop-account/v1/session?storeId=100");

  json = response.then().statusCode(200);
```

But getting 500, log-in works fine without rest-assured though. I'm not getting where am I going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it working with below code

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("emailId", "test@test.com");
params.put("password", "test123");

request = given().
                log().all().
                        header("Host", HOST_HEADER).
                        header("user-agent", USER_AGENT).
                        header("accept", ACCEPT).
                        header("content-type", CONTENT_TYPE).
                        contentType(JSON).
                        body(params);

response = request.when().
                        post(ENDPOINT_FOR_LOGIN);


json = response.then().statusCode(200);



import static io.restassured.http.ContentType.JSON;

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```